# Malformed Ampersand using urllib

Tags: python, html, character-encoding, urllib

I am attempting to parse an html file that is formatted as below. I stored a copy locally and wrote a script to parse the file.

```
ECE 231  <b><u>&amp;</u></b>  Elements of Electrical    (3)|No Comparable Course 
        Engineering                  |                                      
ECE 231L    Elements of Electrical    (1)|                                      
        Engineering Lab              |
```

Everything was working fine, but I discovered a discrepancy between the version I kept locally as an example and the version I was pulling from the site programmatically. I discovered that ampersands weren't being handled the way I was expecting:

```
ECE 231  <B ><U >&</B></U>  Elements of Electrical    (3)|No Comparable Course 
        Engineering                  |                                      
ECE 231L    Elements of Electrical    (1)|                                      
        Engineering Lab              |
```

This was the method I was using to open and read the file.

```
import urllib.request
url = "some url"

file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
contents = file.read()
# contents = file.read().decode('ascii')

f = open('file.html','wb')
f.write( contents )
f.close()
```

All other  and  tags in the document remain unchanged. When I open the file up in the browser and download it again, it reformats the html back to the form I originally assumed it would take.

This is not a major problem, I am just curious as to why would this be the case.

Comment: try to save file as `'w'` and not `'wb'`

Comment: When attempting this with file.read(), I get "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes."

When attempting this with .decode('ascii'), I get the same issue. It's also the same with .decode('utf-8')